# Rendering font size smaller than 1 in Pyglet

Tags: python, font-size, pyglet

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3.8.10 and Pyglet 1.5.21. When I specify very small font size, near or less than one, it renders as a fuzzy blob. Here is an example with font size 0.2. Pixelated texture in the background has 6x6 size for scale:

[image]

I suspect that this is caused by Pyglet using bitmapped fonts instead of meshes. What I would like to see is this rendering from vedo with the same font, rendered as a mesh, and the same background texture:

[image]

Is there an easy way to achieve it with Pyglet?